# Git sub branch merge with other branch

Tags: git-branch

I have created one branch (Sprint1)  from master and created one branch (JIRA1) from Sprint1 branch. We have did some commit in Sprint1 and also in JIRA1 branch. We thought that we can not complete development of JIRA1 and we need to merge the Sprint1 with master branch. We want to start development new Sprint2 with new branch Sprint2.
What is best practice to handle such scenario? Can i merge JIRA1 after development in sprint2 branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned merge in the question, I don't think you would want to rebase. 
Instead, you can merge JIRA1 in SPRINT2 anytime you want.It won't be a problem since (Assuming you have merged SPRINT1 into SPRINT2 or SPRINT2 was created based on SPRINT1) the code base for Sprint 1 and Jira1 is same.

The problem would occur if you try to merge sprint 2 into Jira 1. In that case, you can use git rebase for specific commits of sprint 2.

Answer (score 0):

Sure just merge the changes in `Sprint1` to master, and rebase the `JIRA1` branch onto the `Sprint2` branch using `rebase --onto`

```
git checkout develop
git merge Sprint1
git checkout -b Sprint2
git checkout JIRA1
git rebase --onto Sprint2 Sprint1 JIRA1
```

What this will do is figure out the changes in `JIRA1` branch since it diverged from `Sprint1`, and replay the changes on `JIRA1` branch as if it were based on `Sprint2` to begin with. Makes sense?

[Git rebasing reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Comment: Thanks for quick suggestion.